# `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` with iOS 13 dynamic colors, not automatically refreshing the UI after dark mode toggle

Tags: draw, ios13

I have been tackling a task of adopting the new iOS 13 dynamic colors and I got an implementation that uses the `CGContextSaveGState`, `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`, `CGContextAddPath` etc. to draw a shape on the screen. I think that because CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor requires me to pass the `CGColor` of the `UIColor`, at that point the "dynamic" nature of the color I pass which is `[UIColor labelColor]` basically breaks and is not longer dynamic.

Is anyone aware how to handle such scenarios where I use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` to draw but also want to take advantage and add support for the new iOS 13 dynamic colors?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be fairly easy.

What I had was a `UIView` in which I hold an `NSMutableArray` of `CALayer` instances which use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` and I pass an dynamic color but pass its `CGColor` to the `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`. Then I use the `layoutSublayersOfLayer` to set the `.frame` of those `CALayer` instances. In this scenario in order to update the colors of those `CALayer` instances in which I passed it to  I had to override the traitCollectionDidChange of my `UIView` and call the `setNeedsDisplay`

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection
{ 
    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        if (previousTraitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != UIUserInterfaceStyleUnspecified
            && self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection.userInterfaceStyle) {
            for (CALayer *caLayer in _myCsLayers) {
                [caLayer setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        }
    }
}
```